# jQgrid dblclick cell update filterToolbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I'm creating an application using **jQgrid**, and I'm looking for any ideas for populating `filterToolbar` when user double click on cell.

To be more exact, when user double click on cell I would like cell value to fill `filterToolbar` at corresponding column.

Comment: If what you type in to the textarea in the 'Ask Question' form doesn't contain a question mark, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: Exactly - What have you tried so far, and what did not work?

Comment: Thank you for suggestions I'll try to keep them in mind for the future   post's. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the JQGrid [ondblClickRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aevents) event you will have the iCol value which is the index of the cell that was clicked on in that row. With that index and looking at the row you can get both the name of the column and the value of the cell. Then the filter boxes have the id of **gs_columnname**, so using jquery you can inject the value in to your respective column filter.

```
ondblClickRow: function(rowid,iRow,iCol,e){
    var cm = $("#gridid").jqGrid("getGridParam", "colModel");
    var colName = cm[iCol]["name"];
    var cellvalue = $("#gridid").jqGrid("getCell", rowid, iCol);
    $('#gs_' + colName).val(cellvalue);
},
```

Comment: Thank you very much for reply, it worked nice. Just an update: var colName = cm[iCol]; should be var colName = cm[iCol]["name"];

Comment: @user1375348 Your update is correct and I have made the changes above, and I apologize for missing that. Glad it worked for you, and if you could mark the answer as accepted that would be great.